# Handle files with the same name by automoc

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, automocking

There is the following source tree:

```
*-source
*----subsource
*--------Source1.hpp
*----Source1.hpp
```

Both files, ./Source1.hpp and ./subsource/Source1.hpp, must be handled by moc.
When using automoc it puts output moc files to the same directory with the same name, since it is impossible it overwrites the file.

Qt - 5.2

CMake - 2.8.12

CMake files are rather big, but here is a brief example:

```
# Main CMakeLists.txt
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)


add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/components/Com1" ./Com1)


# Com1 CMakeLists.txt in components/Com1

file(GLOB_RECURSE CPP_FILES source/*.cpp)
add_library(Com1 SHARED ${CPP_FILES})
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Could you show your cmake file? It should not put them into the same directory if you do it right, so the question is: how are you doing it now?

Comment: You have not updated the relevant parts from your cmake file, i.e. we cannot see how the hpp is used, etc.

Comment: This is all related to automoc. There are no any hpp files in my CMakeLists.

Comment: There is already a [ticket for this](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=12873) in the cmake issue tracker.  
For some reason, it completely ignored since 2012 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tracker claims this is fixed in CMake 3.6:

http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=12873